# Retriving a single column result using Hibernate HQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, hql

using Hibernate I have a HQL query that looks like this:

```
String myQuery = " SELECT  code,((max(mid)/min(mid))-1)*100 
FROM ExchangeRate 
WHERE effectivedate >= '2017-09-01'and effectivedate <= '2017-10-22' 
group by name, code order by 2 desc "
```

With this query i want to recive the code of ExchangeRate with biggest diffrence in given time (from 2017-09-01 to 2017-10-22). Since i only want one rate I put a limit on the query and download the result using uniqueResult() method.

```
Session session = CRUDSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Query q = session.createQuery(myQuery);
q.setMaxResults(1);
Object code = q.uniqueResult();
```

The problem is to receive the first column value 'code' as a string which is a varchar in my Postgress database but i can't seem to find a decent solution to do it, since there's also the second column with BigDecimal as a data type. While using debug and variables window the variable code get's the proper values which looks like this:

[Variable window in debugg mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24YLK.png)

Reffering to the object code like an array by using:

```
String myCode = code[0];
```

This obviously does not work since the variable is not an array.

---

EDIT:

The thing that worked for me was casting the Object type from uniqueResult() to an Object array and then using first value of that array:

```
Object[] code = (Object[]) q.uniqueResult();
String myCode = (String) code[0];
```

Comment: `code` looks like an array in the debugger. What exception did you get? Did try type casting it to string?

Comment: Try `Object[] code = q.uniqueResult(); String myCode = (String)code[0];`

Comment: Thanks @SubirKumarSao that worked like a charm.